# Center RelativeLayout or its contents

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm making a little app as I'm learning Android these days and I came up with a little problem, I  made a RelativeLayout (in a java file, not xml file) and then introduced buttons in it one relative to another.

The final layout its like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlHUt.png]

What I do is I create the center top row button and then all the other buttons relative to him. What I'd like to do is to center the RelativeLayout in the view so I the board is centered and I can put some text or anything else in top of the screen. I have thought about creating a LinearLayout before the RelativeLayout and then set something like margin bottom or introduce the RelativeLAyout into another layout to center it, but seems like not working, what do you suggest me to do to achieve that goal without having to change the way I make the board? Here is the code to make the board:

```
private RelativeLayout makeBoard (){
    int papi = 4;
    int grande =3;
    int peque = 1;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wrap_content,wrap_content);
    RelativeLayout parent = new RelativeLayout(this);


    parent.setLayoutParams(params);



    papi = makeRow(parent,papi,peque);
    papi = makeRow(parent,papi,peque);

    papi = makeRow(parent,papi,grande);
    papi = makeRow(parent,papi,grande);
    papi = makeRow(parent,papi,grande);

    papi = makeRow(parent,papi,peque);
    papi = makeRow(parent,papi,peque);
    return parent;
}

private int makeRow (RelativeLayout parent, int papasote,int colDer)
{


    int index = papasote+10;
    if (papasote==4)
    {
        createButtonSinMas (parent, index);
    }
    else
    {
        createButtonJustoAbajo(parent, index, papasote);
    }

    for (int i=0;i<colDer;i++)
    {
        createButtonAlaDeresha(parent, index+i+1, index+i);
        createButtonAlaIskierda(parent, index-i-1, index-i);
    }
    return index;   
}   


private int createButtonSinMas (RelativeLayout parent, int id)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(SIZE, SIZE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,RelativeLayout.TRUE);   
    CCCButton button = new CCCButton(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    return basura(parent,id,params, button);
}   

private int createButtonJustoAbajo (RelativeLayout parent, int id, int papasote)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(SIZE, SIZE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, papasote);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, papasote);
    CCCButton button = new CCCButton(this);
    return basura(parent,id,params, button);

}

private int createButtonAlaDeresha (RelativeLayout parent, int id, int papasote)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(SIZE, SIZE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, papasote);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE,papasote);
    CCCButton button = new CCCButton(this);
    return basura(parent,id,params, button);
}   

private int createButtonAlaIskierda (RelativeLayout parent, int id, int papasote)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(SIZE, SIZE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, papasote);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE,papasote);     
    CCCButton button = new CCCButton(this);
    return basura(parent,id,params, button);
}   

private int basura(RelativeLayout parent,int id,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params, CCCButton button)
{
    button.setId(id);
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);     
    actualizarBoton(button);

    parent.addView(button); 
    return button.getId();  
}
```

Then I just do in my main board=makeBoard(); board being a RelativeLayout variable.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    game = new Game();
    board = makeBoard();
    setContentView(board);  
}
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: how do you add this `board` to the screen/main layout? `setContentView` or something? post that part..

Comment: Yes, I just do setContentView(board) in onCreate, added the onCreate code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making following changes in your code.

Change Layoutparams from wrap_content to match_parent

and set gravity of your relative layout to center.

```
private RelativeLayout makeBoard() {
        int papi = 4;
        int grande = 3;
        int peque = 1;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        RelativeLayout parent = new RelativeLayout(this);

        parent.setLayoutParams(params);
        parent.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


        papi = makeRow(parent, papi, peque);
        papi = makeRow(parent, papi, peque);

        papi = makeRow(parent, papi, grande);
        papi = makeRow(parent, papi, grande);
        papi = makeRow(parent, papi, grande);

        papi = makeRow(parent, papi, peque);
        papi = makeRow(parent, papi, peque);
        return parent;
    }
```

Comment: It worked, I have tried with CENTER_HORIZONTAL but the things were messing. With just CENTER the whole thing works, it looks like this http://i.imgur.com/i5PlOUq.jpg   Thank you!